# ¿por qué puedo acceder a una variable de clase usando una instancia? (python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

en una documentación dice que las variables de clase no se muestran en **dict** de una instancia, entonces porque puedo acceder a una var de clase usando la instancia?

```
>>> class Test:

...     class_varaible = 123

...     def __init__(self):

...             self.instance_variable = 999

>>> 

>>> my_test = Test()

>>> 

>>> my_test.__dict__

{'instance_variable': 999}

>>> 

>>> my_test.class_varaible

123

>>>
```

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to [es.so]. Please translate your question to spanish. Otherwise it will be closed. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al Castellano, de lo contrario terminará cerrada. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Y la documentación está en lo cierto, `instancia.__dict__` almacena los atributos de instancia, en cambio los de clase se almacenan en  `Clase.__dict__`, que no es un diccionario realmente.

El problema es que **en el momento que asignas a través de una referencia a la instancia, creas un atributo de instancia con el mismo nombre que el de clase que lo ensombrece**:

```
class Test:
    class_variable = 123
```

> ```
> >>> test = Test()
> >>> test.class_variable
> 123
> >>> test.__dict__
> {}
> >>> Test.__dict__
> mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'class_variable': 123, .... })
> #                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> >>> test.class_variable = 999
> >>> Test.__dict__
> mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'class_variable': 123, ...})
> #                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> >>> test.__dict__
> {'class_variable': 999}
> ```

El solapamiento del atributo de clase ocurre porque el orden de búsqueda de atributos es:

- 1º Atributos especiales (`__dict__`, `__slots__`, `__weakref__`, etc.).
- 2º Descriptores de datos (implementan `__set__()` o `__delete__()`) en diccionario de clase y posibles clases padre, incluidas las propiedades por tanto.
- **3º** **Atributos de instancia**.
- **4º Descriptores de no-datos** (implementan `__get__()` pero no `__set__()` ni `__delete__()`) **en diccionario de clase y padres**.
- 5º Método `__getattr__`.
- 6º Si nada dio resultado se lanza una excepción `AttributeError`

Como se puede apreciar, Python no busca solo el atributo en instancia.**dict**, busca en la clase y también en las clase padre hasta legar a `object`, pero con un orden claro y establecido.

Primero, como puedes ver, están los atributos de instancia, cuando haces `self.class_variable` (obviando los dos primeros puntos) busca en `test.__dict__` pero sin no se encuentra, cómo es el caso, sigue buscando . Como existe como descriptor de no datos en la clase se retorna. Por eso puedes usar `self.class_variable` para acceder a él.

En el momento que "reasignas", no reasignas realmente, solo puedes reasignar mediante una referencia a la clase, lo que haces es crear un atributo de instancia con el mismo nombre, cómo primero se busca en los de instancia a partir de ahora `self.class_variable` no podrá referenciar al atributo de clase.

Para asignar a un atributo de clase por tanto, o usas una referencia a clase directamente (`Test`, `test.__class__`) o un método de clase (que recibe la referencia de la clase automáticamente como primer argumento):

```
class Test:
    class_variable = 123

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls,  valor):
       cls.class_variable = valor
```

> ```
> >>> test = Test()
> >>> test.__dict__
> {}
> >>> Test.__dict__
> mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'class_variable': 123, ...})
> >>> test.foo(999)
> >>> test.__dict__
> {}
> >>> Test.__dict__
> mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'class_variable': 999, ...})
> >>> Test.class_variable
> 999
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Esto es porque las variables tienen modificadores de acceso, esto hace referencia a que puedes hacer que los atributos de una clase sean públicos o privado. En tu caso son públicos, por ello te deja verlos en el `dict` e imprimir sus valores; En el caso de que quieras tener atributos privados debes definirlos de la siguiente manera:

```
class SistemaOperativo:
    self.__windowsKey = "16D5G8Y6E9R1G4R"
```

usando dos guiones bajos antes del atributo `__windowsKey`, esto mismo aplica para los métodos de la clase, te sugiero leer esto [Python OOP](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)